# Elasticsearch multiple values in one field

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I have a problem in ELK stack and I am not sure what is the cause of that.
A lot of fields in my index have multiple values.
For example:

`records.Type Event, Event, Event, Event`

`records.EventCategory 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1`

`records.EventLevelName Success, Success, Success, Success, Success, Success, Success`

The implementation is quite easy and there's no fancy parsing in place.
I am pulling logs with Logstash from EventHub and store them in Elastic.
The only filter which is in place in Logstash is json filter:

```
filter {
  json {
    add_tag => [ "EventHub" ]
    source => "message"
    remove_field => [ "message" ]
  }
}
```

That's all.
Nothing useful in logs either.
Does anyone faced this problem? I couldn't find any helpful information.

Comment: Nothing useful in this question either...what exactly is the problem?

Comment: The problem is duplicated values in one field. I want to have only one value stored

Comment: Are you saying that the fields are arrays and you only want one value from the array? If so, which one?

Comment: What is the source of your data? Is it from Azure Sentinel? If it is from sentinel you need to use `split` filter after the `json` filter, Sentinel will send multiple events inside an array called `records`.

Comment: Badger probably i want to split them to be separate events. Now i have too many values in on field. I will try leandrojmp suggestion.

leandrojmp source is EventHub

Comment: EventHub is just where your messages are stored, something is sending this data to event hub, it looks like Sentinel or something created by Azure Monitor, that probably has the same format, multiple events inside an array named `records`.

Comment: Yup, i am sorry, you're right. Events are sent from Azure AD.

Comment: Now i got this warn message:
`Only String and Array types are splittable. field:[records][0][properties] is of type = Hash`

Not sure how to handle it

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing what is the original data and how it gets to Logstash. This seems to be some parsing issue of the original event, like if multiple events are merged into one event when it gets to Logstash. How does your logging pipeline looks like before Logstash, and what is your Logstash `input {}` section? Can you also share an example original event before it gets to Logstash?

Comment: hi @akos - my input pipeline pulls logs from eventhub and then passing it to json filter.
input {
 azure_event_hubs {
    event_hub_connections => [ "Endpoint...." ]
    threads => 2
    decorate_events => true
  }

}

filter {
  jsonv { source => [ "message" ] remove_field => [ "message" ]}

}

output { elasticsearch { ... } }

Thats all.
The event is quite big and it would not fit here